# Getting the value of buffers in Python wrapper of OpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl, glumpy, gloo

Is it possible to get the buffer to readable array? i.e. 
When I call them or print them, only


are shown.
How can I get the value of buffer object to python array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different possibilities. One possibility is to use [`glGetBufferSubData`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glGetBufferSubData.html). The data of a [Framebuffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) can be read by [`glReadPixels`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glReadPixels.html), if the buffer is bound for reading (`GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER`). A texture can be read by [`glGetTexImage`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glGetTexImage.html). In general a buffer can be accessed by [Buffer Mapping](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object#Mapping) ([`glMapBuffer`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glMapBuffer.html) / [`glMapBufferRange`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glMapBufferRange.html)).

For instance you can use `glGetBufferSubData` to read floating point values to read the data of a `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`. In the following example `vbo` is a vertex buffer object and `no_of_floats` is the number of floats you want to read.

`glGetBufferSubData` returns an array of bytes. You can use [numpy](https://numpy.org/) to convert the array of bytes to an array of floats:

```py
import numpy as np
```

```py
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
uint8_data = glGetBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, no_of_floats * 4)
float32_data = np.frombuffer(uint8_data, dtype=np.float32)
```

Another option is to generate a [*ctypes*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) array and to read the data directly into the array:

```py
import ctypes
```

```py
float32_data = (ctypes.c_float * no_of_floats)() # or (GLfloat * no_of_floats)()
void_ptr = ctypes.c_void_p(ctypes.addressof(float32_data))

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
glGetBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, no_of_floats * 4, void_ptr)
```